# C# version of WebForms page not working, VB version is

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have two versions of a web form.  The original, in VB.  And the new one, in C#.  They both do essentially the same thing, but the language is different, and the C# version is a little improved feature-wise and readability-wise.  The difference on the .aspx page itself for each one is different by means of the autoeventwireup property on the @Page tag.  Now, when I try to run the VB version I get the results I'm looking for. The C# version does nothing.  In the logs for each page I see that the VB version is getting a POST from the caller, and the C# version is getting a GET from the caller.  So none of the Request.Form values are available to the C# version.  Both pages when deployed are called by a separate web application.

VB Version page.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Custom Label Generator.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

C# version of page.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Custom Label Generator.aspx.cs" Inherits="CustomLabelGenerator.Custom_Label_Generator" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Custom Label Generator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

VB Version code-behind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    'LogEvent("Request to print: " & Date.Today)

    Try
        If Request.Form.Count <= 0 Then
            LogEvent("No label data was submitted with the request.")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        'WRITE LABEL DATA BACK TO REQUESTING CLIENT
        Me.Response.Clear()
        Me.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
        Me.Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(sLabelCode))
        Me.Response.Flush()

    Catch ex As Exception
        LogEvent("Problem generating custom labels. More information: " + ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

C# version code-behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LogHelper.LogEvent("Request to print at: " + DateTime.Now);

        try
        {
            if(Request.Form.Count <= 0)
            {
                LogHelper.LogEvent("No label data was submitted with the request");
                return;
            }
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            Response.BinaryWrite(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(labelCode));
            Response.Flush();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogHelper.LogEvent("Problem generating custom labels. More information :: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            LogHelper.CleanupOldLogs();
        }
    }
```

I've currently got a bunch of code in both to spit out all the request information I can think of. I've also tried undoing the autoeventwireup, but there doesn't seem to be a solid equivalent in C#.  I'm wondering if maybe this would be better as a WebAPI call, force it to only accept POST, and not mess around with any of the other kruft.  I'm not sure if I have the time for that level of conversion, though, so a webforms-based solution would be appreciated!

Update:  dump of Request.Form.Keys from VB version (minus the *USEFUL* keys I need)

```
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,ALL_HTTP => HTTP_CONNECTION:Keep-Alive
HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH:1371
HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
HTTP_EXPECT:100-continue
HTTP_HOST:localhost

9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,ALL_RAW => Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 1371
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Expect: 100-continue
Host: localhost

9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,APPL_MD_PATH => /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/Custom Label Generator
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH => C:\Program Files (x86)\AgileElite\Projects Server\ContentLabelGenerator\
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,AUTH_TYPE => 
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,AUTH_USER => 
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,AUTH_PASSWORD => 
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,LOGON_USER => 
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,REMOTE_USER => 
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,CERT_COOKIE => 
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,CERT_FLAGS => 
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,CERT_ISSUER => 
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,CERT_KEYSIZE => 
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,CERT_SECRETKEYSIZE => 
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,CERT_SERIALNUMBER => 
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,CERT_SERVER_ISSUER => 
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,CERT_SERVER_SUBJECT => 
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,CERT_SUBJECT => 
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,CONTENT_LENGTH => 1371
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,CONTENT_TYPE => application/x-www-form-urlencoded
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,GATEWAY_INTERFACE => CGI/1.1
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,HTTPS => off
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,HTTPS_KEYSIZE => 
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,HTTPS_SECRETKEYSIZE => 
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,HTTPS_SERVER_ISSUER => 
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,HTTPS_SERVER_SUBJECT => 
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,INSTANCE_ID => 1
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,INSTANCE_META_PATH => /LM/W3SVC/1
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,LOCAL_ADDR => ::1
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,PATH_INFO => /Custom Label Generator/Custom Label Generator.aspx
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,PATH_TRANSLATED => C:\Program Files (x86)\AgileElite\Projects Server\ContentLabelGenerator\Custom Label Generator.aspx
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,QUERY_STRING => 
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,REMOTE_ADDR => ::1
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,REMOTE_HOST => ::1
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,REMOTE_PORT => 59112
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,**REQUEST_METHOD => POST**
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,SCRIPT_NAME => /Custom Label Generator/Custom Label Generator.aspx
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,SERVER_NAME => localhost
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,SERVER_PORT => 80
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,SERVER_PORT_SECURE => 0
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,SERVER_PROTOCOL => HTTP/1.1
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,SERVER_SOFTWARE => Microsoft-IIS/7.5
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,URL => /Custom Label Generator/Custom Label Generator.aspx
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,HTTP_CONNECTION => Keep-Alive
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH => 1371
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE => application/x-www-form-urlencoded
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,HTTP_EXPECT => 100-continue
9/23/2015 2:25:10 PM,HTTP_HOST => localhost
```

C# version dump of Request.Params.Keys (other parts are blank)

```
9/23/2015 2:17:04 PM --- Request to print at: 9/23/2015 2:17:04 PM
9/23/2015 2:17:04 PM --- Request.Params.Keys:
9/23/2015 2:17:04 PM --- ALL_HTTP => HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
HTTP_HOST:localhost

9/23/2015 2:17:04 PM --- ALL_RAW => Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: localhost

9/23/2015 2:17:04 PM --- APPL_MD_PATH => /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/Custom Label Generator
9/23/2015 2:17:04 PM --- APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH => C:\Program Files (x86)\AgileElite\Projects Server\ContentLabelGenerator\
9/23/2015 2:17:04 PM --- AUTH_TYPE => 
9/23/2015 2:17:04 PM --- AUTH_USER => 
9/23/2015 2:17:04 PM --- AUTH_PASSWORD => 
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- LOGON_USER => 
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- REMOTE_USER => 
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- CERT_COOKIE => 
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- CERT_FLAGS => 
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- CERT_ISSUER => 
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- CERT_KEYSIZE => 
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- CERT_SECRETKEYSIZE => 
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- CERT_SERIALNUMBER => 
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- CERT_SERVER_ISSUER => 
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- CERT_SERVER_SUBJECT => 
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- CERT_SUBJECT => 
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- CONTENT_LENGTH => 0
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- CONTENT_TYPE => application/x-www-form-urlencoded
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- GATEWAY_INTERFACE => CGI/1.1
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- HTTPS => off
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- HTTPS_KEYSIZE => 
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- HTTPS_SECRETKEYSIZE => 
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- HTTPS_SERVER_ISSUER => 
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- HTTPS_SERVER_SUBJECT => 
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- INSTANCE_ID => 1
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- INSTANCE_META_PATH => /LM/W3SVC/1
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- LOCAL_ADDR => ::1
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- PATH_INFO => /Custom Label Generator/Custom Label Generator
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- PATH_TRANSLATED => C:\Program Files (x86)\AgileElite\Projects Server\ContentLabelGenerator\Custom Label Generator
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- QUERY_STRING => 
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- REMOTE_ADDR => ::1
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- REMOTE_HOST => ::1
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- REMOTE_PORT => 58997
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- **REQUEST_METHOD => GET**
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- SCRIPT_NAME => /Custom Label Generator/Custom Label Generator
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- SERVER_NAME => localhost
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- SERVER_PORT => 80
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- SERVER_PORT_SECURE => 0
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- SERVER_PROTOCOL => HTTP/1.1
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- SERVER_SOFTWARE => Microsoft-IIS/7.5
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- URL => /Custom Label Generator/Custom Label Generator
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE => application/x-www-form-urlencoded
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- HTTP_HOST => localhost
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- /******************  Request.Form.Keys:  ***********************/
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- /******************  Request.Form.AllKeys:  ***********************/
9/23/2015 2:17:05 PM --- /******************  Request.QueryString.Keys:  ***********************/
```

Comment: would be good if you included the error :)

Comment: there isn't really an error.  It just regurgitates all the request data. the vb version happens to say it's a POST and the C# version says its a GET.  Should I put that up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matt,
I've encountered the 'POST' mysteriously changing to a 'GET' before also.  It is probably being redirected due to FriendlyUrlSettings that are defaulted in VS2013 and above.

One workaround: go to the App_Start folder in the RouteConfig.ResgisterRoutes and set settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off

```
 public static class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
    }
}
```

Checkout this link for more info on FriendlyUrls: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx

Comment: this was the trick.  I tried creating the project anew in VS 2012 and had no problems, so I went back and did this in the VS 2013 solution and that seemed to do the trick!

Answer (score 4):

Matt,

The reason for this behavior is an attempt to reduce the chances for multiple form submissions.  The theory behind this is known as POST-REDIRECT-GET.  From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get:

> When a web form is submitted to a server through an HTTP POST request, a web user that attempts to refresh the server response in certain user agents can cause the contents of the original HTTP POST request to be resubmitted, possibly causing undesired results, such as a duplicate web purchase.
>
> To avoid this problem, many web developers use the PRG pattern[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) — instead of returning a web page directly, the POST operation returns a redirection command. The HTTP 1.1 specification introduced the HTTP 303 ("See other") response code to ensure that in this situation, the web user's browser can safely refresh the server response without causing the initial HTTP POST request to be resubmitted. However most common commercial applications in use today (new and old alike) still continue to issue HTTP 302 ("Found") responses in these situations.

Answer (score 0):

Matt why don't you just put a method="POST" in your form?

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" method="post">
```

Comment: I did try that but it didn't seem to help in this case.

Comment: Even if you put method post it does a GET?

Comment: yes, see Derek and Jobrocol's answers for the explanations why.

Comment: Since this redirect is a good thing, probably you can get your data directly from Request object and not from Request.Form, this way even if was a Get you can access the data

Comment: I looked at that as well.  the reason I found out I was doing a GET instead of POST was because I wrote all of the properties of the request object to a log file.  The request data I was looking for was not there.

Answer (score 0):

Matt,

Was this intentional?

VB
Inherits="_Default"

C#
Inherits="CustomLabelGenerator.Custom_Label_Generator"

Comment: Yeah whoever wrote the VB version I think just renamed some things.  I created a new page, but the names of the classes and files all match up in the C# version